# how to correctly change machine name?

Tags: hostname

I've changed my machine name through editing /etc/hostname file. but since I did, a weird message appears whenever I sudo:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host Tehuti
```

then it asks for password normally.

What is wrong and is there a correct way to change name with causing problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your hosts file(`/etc/hosts`), for the entry of 127.0.1.1
Set your new hostname there as well.
So probably for you:

`127.0.1.1                             Tehuti`

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit /etc/hosts too. Replace old name with new name.